# How to create PHP array from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table:

```
-------------------
|type_id|type_name| 
-------------------
|  22   | Toyota  |
|  22   | Mazda   |
|  23   | Volvo   |
|  23   |  Man    |
|  25   | Scania  |
|  25   | Iveco   |
|  25   | Fiat    |
-------------------
```

which is created dynamically from user input. I want to create an array from the table using PHP like this:

```
array(
    '22' => array('Toyota', 'Mazda'),
    '23' => array('Volvo', 'Man'),
    '25' => array('Scania', 'Iveco','Fiat'),
);
```

where array id will be type_id and elements will be type_name's of the type_id.I tried this:

```
$results = array();
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $results[] = $line;
    }   
    print_r($results);
```

But I am getting:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [type_id] => 22 
            [type_name] => Toyota
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [type_name] => 22 
            [type_name] => Mazda
        )
    ...so on
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you try anything? I suggest to use loops...

Comment: did you tried anything,paste here. We can't do full code for you. Please show your effort

Comment: @BibanCS  check my answer.

Comment: Is the order of the makes within each group important? If so, you need to include some way of defining that order. Usually this is done through the mechanism of a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: `SELECT type_id, GROUP_CONCAT(type_name) FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY type_id` this query will give you exactly what you are looking for. PHP processing is not needed.

Comment: @MilanChheda  it will give comma separated string values not array what he want .like:-`array(
    '22' =>'Toyota', 'Mazda',..... so on)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie - Hmm, won't it be easier and better to get the desired result from query? And may be use minimal PHP. You are right, it would be comma separated, so would have to use `explode()`

Comment: @MilanChheda  no, only a small change in php record  fetching code will lead hi to desired output. Check my answer for that

Comment: Yup, saw your answer and its perfect for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code a bit and it will work fine:-

```
$results = array(); 
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
  $results[$line['type_id']][] = $line['Type_name'];  //check change here
} 
print_r($results);
```

Note:- check your column-names and correct them if any mistake is there.

Comment: @BibanCS  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your db name and table name in the code-

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
$query ="select * from table";
$exe = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$input = array();
$type = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)) 
{
    if(array_key_exists($result['type_id'], $input))
    {
        $type[] = $result['type_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $type = array($result['type_name']);
    }
    $input[$result['type_id']] = $type;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($input);
```

Comment: is there any mistake on above code ? i would like to know about it. you have several way to do this. this is one of the way. if it is wrong or it doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: OP don't need to change his complete code like you.Just a small change in his fetching data will lead him to desired output as he said that he is able to fetch record fine.BTW not a down-voter

Comment: Thanks mate. In the starting when i see his post he didn't have the code ...later he uploaded it so i couldn't able to see his code....

Answer (score 0):

select type_id and Type_name columns from table and in foreach loop do this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($result as $item){
    $output[$item['type_id']][] = $item['Type_name'];
}
```